# How to prevent sharing same object?

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer

My program takes an array of thread and it also contains a "Queue" class defined by me which takes "Work" object from main() and pushes them in thread class.

```
class Queue {
volatile boolean value = false;
int i;
Work[] WI;
public Queue(int num) {
    this.WI = new Work[num];
    this.i = 0;
    }
synchronized void enqueue(Work WI) {
    if (value) {
        try {
            wait();} catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    this.WI[i++] = WI;
    value = true;
    notify();
}
synchronized Work dequeue() {
    if (!value) {
        try {
            wait();} catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    value = false;
    notify();
    return this.WI[i - 1];
 }
}
```

Here is my Thread class it takes "Work" object and calculates.

```
class Thread_Produce implements Runnable {

Work WI;
Queue q;
int row, column,n,s, start;
Thread t;
public Thread_Produce(Queue q,int n) {
    this.q = q;
    t = new Thread(this);
    this.n = n;
    this.s = 0;
    this.start = 0;
    t.start();
}

public void run() {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                this.WI = (Work) q.dequeue();
                for (int i = 0; i < WI.array1[0].length; i++) {
                    s = s + WI.array1[WI.row][i] * WI.array2[WI.column][i];
                }
                System.out.println(s);
                s = 0;
            }
}
```

But though i made "Queue" class methods synchronized my thread arrays shares same "Work" object from the "Queue". One array enters into the run method without the proper execution of the previous one. What should i do?

Comment: And as nobody has told you yet: read about java naming conventions. Looking at your code makes my eyes hurt, and my brain ouch. Ouch. And then: use names that mean something. Even in 2016 there was *no* point in naming things using single characters only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont reinvent the wheel, use existing one:

Use `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` as your queue insteed of creating your own. It is 100% thread safe without synchronization.

Comment: but i want to handle it by my own using wait() and notify()

Comment: Is there any decent reason for that or it is just for learning purposes?

Comment: @iamblake Start by reading and understanding the source code of the JDK solution then. Your current solution has multiple serious bugs - concurrent and just plain semantic. It's also slower than it could be, but first should be the correctness problems.

Comment: @Voo i'm quite new in threading , can you please tell me where i can find jdk solution?

Comment: @IAmBlake start from concurrent linked queue;)

Comment: @IAmBlake the whole source code should be included as a zip file with the jdk and any even moderately useful IDE should allow you to navigate the source code like you would do with your own code. Eclipse and intellij both do at least. You'll see that production worthy code is something completely different to student projects, but you can learn a great deal from it. Don't be disheartened if you don't understand everything from the start

Answer (score 0):

Your code like this:

```
if (condition)
    wait();
```

doesn't work. The wait method releases the lock and puts the calling thread in a waiting state. Once the thread wakes up from waiting it has to acquire the lock before it can leave the call to wait. But at that point the thread has no idea what state things are in. Receiving a notification doesn't guarantee that the notified thread can acquire the lock right away, some other thread may have acted inbetween the notification and the acquisition of the lock.

Instead always call wait in a loop so that when your thread wakes it checks the condition it's waiting on once it has the lock. See the Oracle tutorials,  especially [the Guarded Blocks page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html).

Also you are using notify for two separate cases. When a thread is notified it is chosen for the notification arbitrarily, it might be for something relevant or it might not, and if the notification isn't relevant to the thread that happens to receive it then that notification is lost. Use notifyall instead and at least you know if it is relevant to any waiting thread then it will get acted on.

Instead of using a flag, just check if there's anything in the array.

Comment: you mean while(value) in stead of if(value) ?

Comment: @IAmBlake: Yes. Once you reacquire the lock you need to check the value again.